# Installing Net::SMTP::SSL

Tags: perl, email, ssl

Hello I have run across a problem when I try to use Net::SMTP::SSL on my Mac (running OS X 10.10).  I have a perl script that runs fine using Net::SMTP::SSL, it looks like this:

```
use Net::SMTP::SSL;

use strict;
use Carp;
use Pod::Usage;

sub send_mail {
my $to = 'phone@server.com';
my $subject = $_[1];
my $body = $_[2];

my $from = 'mail@server.com';
my $password = 'password';

my $smtp;

if (not $smtp = Net::SMTP::SSL->new('smtp.gmail.com',
    Port => 465,
    Debug => 1)) {
        die "Could not connect to server\n";
    }

$smtp->auth($from, $password)
|| die "Authentication failed!\n";

$smtp->mail($from . "\n");
my @recepients = split(/,/, $to);
foreach my $recp (@recepients) {
    $smtp->to($recp . "\n");
}
$smtp->data();
$smtp->datasend("From: " . $from . "\n");
$smtp->datasend("To: " . $to . "\n");
$smtp->datasend("Subject: " . $subject . "\n");
$smtp->datasend("\n");
$smtp->datasend($body . "\n");
$smtp->dataend();
$smtp->quit;
}

# Send away!
&send_mail('mail@server.com', 'Server just blew up', 'Some more detail');
```

I also have another script (in a separate folder) that starts off as:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl -Ilib
use Net::SMTP::SSL;
```

my problem is that the second script doesn't work.  I get a command line error reporting it can't find Net/SMTP/SSL.pm in @INC

I have the problem narrowed down to the shebang part #!/usr/bin/env perl -Ilib but I haven't a clue how to fix it. Any suggestions?

Comment: you need cpan install it first. http://www.cpan.org/modules/INSTALL.html

Comment: Do I understand correctly that both of these scripts, the working and non-working ones are on the same Mac?  If so, then Net::SMTP::SSL clearly IS installed on that machine, so that's probably not it.  Why are you using the -I flag with lib?  That just adds "lib" to the start of the module search path that @INC contains, which probably isn't what you want.  Why do you need "lib" in the module search path?

Comment: I installed with CPAN and like ratsbane said one of the scripts work.  I'm not quite sure why the -Ilib is there.  I inherited this script as is and am just trying to add SMTP funtionality to it. there is a "lib" folder with some .pm's in it so I assume it is accessing those files and that is why that -Ilib flag is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently realized how old [Net::SMTP::SSL](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SMTP::SSL) is when I tried to investigate a failing script. Loading the module fails due to

```
no strict 'refs';
foreach ( keys %Net::SMTP:: ) {
    next unless defined *{$Net::SMTP::{$_}}{CODE};
    *{$_} = \&{"Net::SMTP::$_"};
}
```

in `Net/SMTP/SSL.pm`:

```
[~/tmp/Net-SMTP-SSL-1.01]> prove -vb t/test.t
t/test.t ..
1..1
not ok 1 - use Net::SMTP::SSL;

#   Failed test 'use Net::SMTP::SSL;'
#   at t/test.t line 2.
#     Tried to use 'Net::SMTP::SSL'.
#     Error:  Not a GLOB reference at /Users/.../tmp/Net-SMTP-SSL-1.01/blib/lib/Net/SMTP/SSL.pm line 16.
# Compilation failed in require at t/test.t line 2.
# BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/test.t line 2.
# Looks like you failed 1 test of 1.
Dubious, test returned 1 (wstat 256, 0x100)
Failed 1/1 subtests
...
Result: FAIL
```

It turns out in the intervening decade, [Net::SMTP](http://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SMTP) now incorporates the required functionality. So, just use that.

```
$ perl -MNet::SMTP -E 'say Net::SMTP->can_ssl'
IO::Socket::SSL
```

Comment: Thanks Sinan, I will try that.  Admittedly, i am following a tutorial a decade old: http://robertmaldon.blogspot.com/2006/10/sending-email-through-google-smtp-from.html  but it seems to work for one script for some odd reason.  You are saying to nix the Net::SMTP::SSL in favor of the Net::SMTP module, is that right?

Comment: Yes, use a recent version of `Net::SMTP` which is actively being developed instead of `Net::SMTP::SSL` which served fine for a long time, but its latest version is now a decade old. HTH.